# Unit conversion of input to/output of public functions/methods

Tags: object-oriented, python, decorator

### The question/s

I'm working on a small scientific Python package. Many of the public methods it is going to offer will have to deal with dimensional input. A wavelength, for example, which could be available to the user in microns or as the equivalent vacuum photon frequency or who knows how.

I could simply state what units a method expects in its documentation and leave it at that, however, from a user perspective, I find having to think about unit conversion very annoying and I know from experience that it is a great source of errors. For this reason, I would like to use a ready-made unit conversion package (probably [`astropy.units`](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/units/) due to my background) to take care of converting arguments to public methods to some unit system internal to the package so that private (or hidden, since we're talking about Python) methods don't have to "think" about units.

- **Are there arguments against this approach apart from more development work compared to simply stating expected units in the documentation?**
- **What design choices are there for implementing this?**

---

### An example

Say I have the following (freely invented) hidden function:

```py
def _foo(l):
    """
    Photon foobar length.

    Parameters
    ----------
    l : float
        Wavelength [micron].

    Returns
    -------
     : float
        Foobar length [micron].
    """
    return l/_bar(l)
```

Where `_bar` does something non-trivial that might even involve calling compiled C extensions.

I would like the public counterpart `foo` of `_foo` to behave as follows:

```py
>>> import astropy.units as u
>>> foo(1*u.m)
<Quantity 0.5 m>
>>> foo(1*u.micron)
<Quantity 0.1 micron>
>>> foo(1)
0.1
```

---

### My research so far

People must have dealt with similar problems before, but apparently I don't know what terminology to use for searching.

The best approach I can think of is using a decorator to do the work:

```py
foo = unit_decorator(_foo,
                     arg_units=['wavelength'],
                     kwarg_units={},
                     out_units=['length']
)
```

This requires typing out what each argument represents, but I guess there's no way around that. The more important concern I have with this approach is that it's not extremely obvious that a change in `_foo`'s signature probably requires changing the above code as well. With duck typing that might produce subtle bugs.

---

Feel free to suggest tags to use for this question, I wasn't really sure which ones apply.

Comment: I'm still trying to get me head around your use case for this. If I have 5 kg and 10 meters does multiplying them in this package give me 50 kilogram-meters? 50J? Or does it just convert from system to system like feet to meters?

Comment: @candied_orange in `astropy.units`, if you're talking about that, you would get 50 kilogram-meters and if you multiplied that by cm and divided by s**2 you could convert it to J. For my package the idea would be to give users the possibility to input e.g. an energy in any unit (J, eV, erg) and to have `astropy` convert it to some default energy unit. Then you can internally just use the `value` (float or numpy array) instead of the `Quantity` in `astropy` linguo.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you wrote

> to take care of converting arguments to public methods to some unit system internal to the package so that private (or hidden, since we're talking about Python) methods don't have to "think" about units.

so for yourself, you already see the major drawback of the "arbitrary unit" approach: it is way less tedious any less error prone to make a decision for **one** unit system and use that consistently throughout your whole code base.

But the same argument applies to **the users of your package**: they will probably experience the same observation! So they may be much happier if you offer them just one system.

Of course, if those users have to import many different packages, and all of these packages are using different conventions, they would benefit from having a standard way for doing those conversion. Ultimately, you will have to ask them, what they prefer and how they intend to use your package. They may ask you

- to provide one unit system, maybe consistent with something they are already used to
- to provide one version of the package with a global switch (for example, between metric and non-metric system)
- to provide only some functions in two or three different variants, each one accepting a different scale of numbers
- or exactly what you suggested: a package where every function can deal with arbitrary units.

But beware, chances are high that in case you add the fullest possible flexibility to your package, almost noone uses that.

Comment: Thank you, I guess there's not much of a point in implementing something fancy no one will use. Except for me feeling good about myself :-D. If it turns out that people would want this feature, do you have any suggestions on the implementation itself?

Answer (score -2):

**Make the parameter strongly typed, and make the type responsible for performing the conversions.**

An example of this pattern is the C# [`TimeSpan`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netframework-4.8) class. Instances can be obtained from various static methods with self-documenting names like `FromMinutes`. And through properties like `TotalMinutes`, the value of an instance can be expressed in various units.

Following this pattern, your methods could accept a `Wavelength` type that can be constructed and expressed in various units, with all instances having the same internal representation.